# UITableViewCell content does not show

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have delegate method that retrieves the content for each cell like this:

```
-(void)getRetrievedShopContentStickerName:(NSArray *)stickerNameArray price:(NSArray *)stickerPriceArray profileBackgroundImage:(NSArray *)stickerProfileBackgroundImageArray profile:(NSArray *)stickerProfileImageArray profileMenuImage:(NSArray *)stickerProfileMenuImageArray designerName:(NSArray *)designerNameArray
{
    self.stickerPriceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:stickerPriceArray];
    self.stickerProfileBGImageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:stickerProfileBackgroundImageArray];

    NSLog(@"sticker price: %@", self.stickerPriceArray);
    NSLog(@"sticker bg: %@", self.stickerProfileBGImageArray);

    [self.shopTableView reloadData];
}
```

This delegate methods logs out a working an array as expected. This is code I used for displaying table view content:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.stickerPriceArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        AsyncImageView *backgroundImage = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)]; //does cell frame get before this method?
        [backgroundImage setTag:123];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundImage];

        UILabel *priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];
        [priceLabel setTag:124];
        [priceLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:30.0f]];
        [priceLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:priceLabel];
    }

    [(AsyncImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:123] loadImageWithTypeFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.stickerProfileBGImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] contentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit imageNameBG:nil];
    [(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:124] setText:[self.stickerPriceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}
```

The only change I get after reloading the table view in the delegate method is the height of each tableviewcell. Why doesn't my contents show? What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about the datasource and delegate of the tableView? Is it bound to the viewController?

Comment: @ingaham yes it is. break point works....

Comment: stickerPriceArray is a strong property (I assume yes, but to be sure)?

Comment: getRetrievedShopContentStickerName is called on the main thread?

Comment: It is strange, that the frame of the backgroundImage and priceLabel is mutch more bigger than the cell size. Did you try with 'normal' size?

Comment: @ingaham yes it is a strong property. and it is on main thread. I tried normal size.. still empty cells

Comment: What about using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: (at this case, the cell won't be nil and you have to register the UITableViewCell with registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:) Can you try it?

Comment: @ingaham found my mistake. I accidentally set the cell identifier in the storyboard. So the if (cell==nil) was never called :/ Anyways thank you for your help :D

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you! Good luck with coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally set my cell's identifier in the storyboard so the `if (cell == nil)` was never called.